# Searching array twice

Tags: c, algorithm

This is a hackerrank problem. 
Find out the maximum movies that can be watched. Assume the list to be distinct movies.

Input:
movieStart[] = {10,12,9,14,16,14}

movieEnd[] = {11,13,15,16,18,18}

Output : 4 (10-11,12-13,14-16,16-18)

Below code is giving me correct output. Would like to know the best solution possible for this problem.
Also what algorithm is used to solve this kind of problem?

```
static int getMaxMovies(int[] movie_start, int[] movie_end) {

    int cnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < movie_start.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < movie_start.length; j++) {

            if  (movie_start[j] == movie_start[i] && movie_end[j] == movie_end[i]) {
                continue;
            }

            if  (movie_start[j] >= movie_start[i] && movie_end[j] <= movie_end[i]) {
                cnt += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return movie_start.length - cnt;

}
```

Comment: Does this problem have a URL?

Comment: This isn't C - the code example includes a `.length` property on arrays, what language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's "Activity selection" problem - which could be easily solved with `O(n)` (in case of sorted input) or `O(nlogn)` (when input isn't sorted) greedy algorithm. If input is already sorted by finishing (end) time you should pick movies which doesn't conflict with previously selected movie.

Pseudocode:

```
Sort by finish times

int previouslySelectedIndex = 0;
int watchedMoviesCount = 1;

for (int i=1; i<movie_end.Length; i++)
{
    if (movie_start[i] >= movie_end[previouslySelectedIndex)
    {
        watchedMoviesCount++;
        previouslySelectedIndex=i;
    }
}
```